# What is the simplest way to validate an ini file in C#?

Tags: .net, ini

Part of my program involves saving and loading settings from an INI file. The end users can edit the INI file from within the program. My question is: is there an easy way to ensure that my INI file is valid before the program saves the new file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to write my own validation. I figured out and wrote parsing while waiting for this response, validation is simple enough.

Answer (score 1):

INI file are deprecated and you are on your own to check the correctness of their structure.
Better use configuration settings or simple XML files.
However, if your are really stuck with this format I can suggest a free library found at this link [INI-Parser](http://code.google.com/p/ini-parser/).
This library has also a 'relaxed syntax parser' that allow not formally correct INI files to be read and used.

Comment: I just looked at that and it's probably just easier to validate the INI myself when modified in the program.

Answer (score 0):

You can check every value manually and see if it contains the right values
I know there are selfmade parsers around but I myself am a big fan of the parser of windows kernel.

http://www.ehow.com/how_5154834_write-ini-files-c.html

good luck :)